# How to update a value to 0 if the result is null after a delete trigger in SQlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers

I have 2 Sqlite tables, lets call them `main` and `sub`.

`Main` has a field which should be the sum of all values with the same code in the sub table.

so if `Main` has

```
CODE  | TOTAL_UNITS_AVAILABLE 
1            3
2            5
```

Then it means in `sub` there's something like this

```
INGREDIENT_CODE  | UNITS_AVAILABLE
     1              1
     1              2
     2              5
```

I have triggers on `sub` for `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` which update the value of `TOTAL_UNITS_AVAILABLE` in `Main` for the record with the code that was inserted/updated/deleted on `sub`

`Insert` and `update` work fine, but `DELETE` has a problem where if every record in `sub` with an X main code gets deleted, the sum of amount in main gets updated to `NULL`.

I tried the following to prevent it but it's not working:

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateAmountAvailable_UPDATE
AFTER DELETE ON Sub
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Main
            SET 
                TOTAL_UNITS_AVAILABLE = (
                    SELECT
                        CASE SUM(A.UNITS_AVAILABLE)
                            WHEN NULL THEN 0
                            WHEN 0 THEN 0
                            ELSE SUM(A.UNITS_AVAILABLE)
                        END
                    FROM Sub AS A
                    WHERE A.INGREDIENT_CODE = old.INGREDIENT_CODE
                ) WHERE CODE = old.INGREDIENT_CODE;
    END
```

Is there any workaround I could try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sqlite has a non-standard aggregate function [TOTAL](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html)

> The sum() and total() aggregate functions return sum of all non-NULL
> values in the group. If there are no non-NULL input rows then sum()
> returns NULL but total() returns 0.0.

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateAmountAvailable_DELETE
AFTER DELETE ON Sub
BEGIN
  UPDATE Main
  SET TOTAL_UNITS_AVAILABLE = (
    SELECT TOTAL(A.UNITS_AVAILABLE) 
    FROM Sub AS A
    WHERE A.INGREDIENT_CODE = old.INGREDIENT_CODE
  )       
  WHERE CODE = old.INGREDIENT_CODE;
END
```

The same using the standard SUM function would be  `COALESCE(SUM(A.UNITS_AVAILABLE), 0)`

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=041194eb8eb237bbe46ade3bde445791)